# When should I use quotes in git?

Tags: git, quotes

For sake of example, presume I have

```
Directory/
      nameOfFile.txt
      nameOfDirectory/
                ...
```

I have always been using the format `git add Directory/nameOf*` but in different documentation, I have seen `git add 'Directory/nameOf*'`.

Just tried `git add "Directory/nameOf*"` and it worked.

Also tried `git commit -m Message with no quotes` and it worked too.

So will Git allow no quotes/quotes interchangably or is this only certain circumstances or versions? Beyond what it will allow, what are the standard protocols for no quotes, single, and double quotes?

Comment: As a best practice its better to add " when adding commit message (git commit -m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question really has nothing to do with `git` and everything to do with your shell.

Most shells "tokenize" the command line -- that is, split it into a sequence of discrete elements -- using whitespace.  So, for example...

```
rm one file
```

...will attempt to remove a file named `one` and a file named `file`, whereas...

```
rm 'one file'
```

...will attempt to remove a single file named `one file`.  So for your examples, using quotes or not doesn't particularly matter, because none of your filenames contains spaces.  The one exception is the `commit` example; if `message` contains spaces you would need to quote it, other wise you'll get:

```
$ git ci -m this is a test
error: pathspec 'is' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

And in fact, there's one other point worth considering: quoting text typically inhibits wildcard expansion, so if I have a file named `nameOfFile.txt` and I do this...

```
rm nameOf*.txt
```

...it will work just fine, but if I do this:

```
rm 'nameOf*.txt'
```

...I will get an error:

```
rm: cannot remove `nameOf*.txt': No such file or directory
```

However, it looks like `git` actually performs filename expansion itself if the shell doesn't do it, so your examples with wildcards will work.

Comment: Side note: I've always been deeply suspicious of git doing its own file name expansion: `echo evil > '**/*'` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using some strange shell, none of those quotes is being seen by git. The quotes would instead be stripped by the shell. Using the quotes would prevent the shell from interpreting the `*` in the pattern leaving that for git.  In many cases it won't matter if that type of expansion is done by the shell or by git, but sometimes it will such as if you're operating on the git index rather than the filesystem as with `git rm --cached`.

The quotes would also prevent a space from being interpreted by the shell as separating arguments. Quoting a single argument that contains spaces will almost always be necessary. The commit command that you give should not work, and it doesn't for me.

Usually the type of quote that you use won't matter.  The most common cases where that will matter will be if the argument being quoted contains one type of quote it will probably be easier to use the other, and if the argument is supposed to contain a `$` it may be better to use single quotes. Within double quotes you can use `\` to escape a `"`, `$`, or (another) `\` which you want to be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

it's based the shell you're using. I just escape spaces and other characters with  \

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes would work because the shell handles them so that you can have spaces in file names etc. So `git add foo/bar` is the same as `git add "foo/bar"`.

Likewise, `git commit -m Foobar` would be the same as `git commit -m "Foobar"`. In both of these cases, `git` will see `Foobar` as the single parameter defining the message. However, if `git commit -m "foo bar"` does the same as `git commit -m foo bar` that means that `git commit -m` accepts multiple command line parameters and pieces them together for your message (seems odd) since in the first case, it sees a single message text parameter of `foo bar` and in the second it sees separate parameters `foo` and `bar`.